# Cancel google cloud functions timeOut retrying

Tags: firebase, timeout, google-cloud-functions

I'm using google cloud functions from firebase to make requests to an external service. The problem is that the response takes more than 9 minutes to be received and exceeds the execution time limit.

I would like to know how to cancel a new automatic attempt of the cloud functions.

Comment: Can you provide some extra information?  What type of trigger are you using?  Do you have control over the external service or is it 3rd party?  Nine minutes is a long time for a response.  It's hard to answer with the information provided.

Comment: Same is happening here. Did you find any solution?